# Customize Google Chrome browser to contain a single webpage

Tags: google-chrome, prism, mozilla

Is there any way to customize Google Chrome? Which technology/language would be used? Is it possible to build a customized version with no toolbars and a webpage inside (I'm interested in something like [this one](http://prism.mozillalabs.com/), but for Chrome)?

Comment: You can make chrome extension..http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you are talking about web apps. You can start Chrome from command line like this:

```
chrome --app=http://stackoverflow.com/
```

You can also add the `--start-maximized` command line switch if you want that window to be maximized.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent the user from clicking external links?

Comment: And: is it possible to distribute a commercial "app" based on Chrome?

Comment: @Lotus: Concerning external links - I don't know. Might be possible if you create a proper web app (http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/apps.html) and use the extensions API to prevent the user from navigating to other sites. Concerning commercial apps - have a look at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/.